# Asterisk выводит бесконечную кучу уведомлений

Tags: centos, asterisk, pjsip

Астериск периодически выводит огромную кучу уведомлений. Хотелось бы понять причину и избавится от этого. Софтфоны исправно подключаются, мне непонятно, что это за подключения.

Файл pjsip.conf:

```
[simpletrans]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
 
[5001]
type = endpoint
context = internal
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
transport=simpletrans
aors = 5001
auth = auth5001
 
[5001]
type = aor
max_contacts = 1
remove_existing=yes
 
[auth5001]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=4444
username=5001
 
[5002]
type = endpoint
context = internal
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
transport=simpletrans
aors = 5002
auth = auth5002
 
[5002]
type = aor
max_contacts = 1
remove_existing=yes
 
[auth5002]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=4444
username=5002
```

Вывод в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вас хацкают хацкиры. Поставьте fail2ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал Alexander Prokoshev, кто-то пытался подключиться к моему Asterisk и настройка брандмауэра с fail2ban помогла.